# Free GIS server to get Geographical data

Tags: java, gis

I need to get additional geographical data such as whether conditions, population density of a given place from a GIS server to my Java application. Could you please give me some free GIS servers which can be used for that.
It should provide an API so that I can easily communicate with it from my application.

Comment: Maybe you get this answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this link:- http://openweathermap.org/api
Yahoo also provides apis to get weather data:- https://developer.yahoo.com/weather/
Hope it'll help. cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can find GIS data from Here.Since it provide API it will more convenient
https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java

or add the dependency

`<dependency>
    <groupId>com.esri.geometry</groupId>
    <artifactId>esri-geometry-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>`